# python how to get all images which are not part of the template

Tags: python, image, xpath

I'm looking for a way to extract all main images of a web page. the easy way is to do it with lxml

```
import lxml.html
import requests
html = requests.get('https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image').text()

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
img = tree.xpath('//img[@src]']
```

this way we get all images, including logos, icons, pictos, sprite css...etc what I would like to get is only real images that are in the content. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You have to figure that out.  There is certain no universal standard for separating those.  Perhaps they are in specific `<div>` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
//div[@id="mw-content-text"]//img[@src]
```